# Display only Description from SPFieldUrlValue

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have written the following code:

```
string link = string.Format("{0}Person.aspx?accountname={1}", mySite, listItem["Name"]);
SPFieldUrlValue spFieldUrlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
spFieldUrlValue.Url = link;
spFieldUrlValue.Description = listItem["ImnName"].ToString();

phoneListItem["FullName"] = spFieldUrlValue;
phoneListItem.Update();
```

but it displays "FullName" field in View like "http://minint-3ihn2o7/my/Person.aspx?accountname=XDOM\smithj, John Smith" but I need to display "John Smith" only (and, of course, field still needs to be a link).

Any ideas how to modify the code to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found answer myself:

Idea is to modify SPField in the SPList

    phoneList.Fields.Delete("FullName");
    phoneList.Fields.Add("FullName", SPFieldType.URL, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change the type of "FullName" field. At the moment it is just Text, so it displays the link and the description as text.